# How to algebraically arrive at the conclusion that $(5-1)^{11} \cdot 2 = 2*5 (\cdots) + (-1)^{11}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This week at uni we was doing modular arithmetic in our math course. In an example our teacher showed us during a lecture, one wanted to find out if the sum of two numbers was dividable by five.

One of the steps was to write the numbers so that you clearly saw that they were dividable by five. A part of one such example is when you write that

$$(5-1)^{11} \cdot 2 = 2*5 (\cdots) + (-1)^{11}.$$

My question though is, how did he arrive there? I understand the logic, but I do not understand how he arrived there.

> How to algebraically arrive at the conclusion that $(5-1)^{11} \cdot 2 = 2*5 (\cdots) + (-1)^{11}$?

Comment: you can arrive at that using Binomial Theorem

Comment: Just put $x$ instead of $5$ and $y$ instead of $-1$ and try to evaluate $(x+y)^{11}$. Also in the right side you should have: $2\times 5\times (\dots) + 2 \times (-1)^{11}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binomial Theorem states that, where n is a positive integer:

$$(a + b)^n= a^n + (^nC_1)a^{n-1}b + (^nC_2)a^{n-2}b^2 +\cdots+ (^nC_{n-1})ab^{n-1} + b^n$$
Now put $a=5$ and $b=-1$ and you will get your result as,
$$(5 -1)^{11}= 5^{11} + (^{11}C_1)5^{10}{(-1)} + (^{11}C_2)5^{9}{(-1)}^2 +\cdots+ (^{11}C_{10})5{-1}^{10} + {(-1)}^{11}$$

Answer (score 1):

The point of modular arithmetic is to be able to adjust your number system, so that you identify a given number (the modulus) with 'zero'. In this case, you identify 5 with 0, so that $(5 - 1)^{11}$ is just $(0 - 1)^{11} \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$.

To see things 'algebraically', you can also apply the binomial theorem to the left hand side. This gives

$\displaystyle (5-1)^{11} = \sum_{j=0}^{11} \binom{11}{j} 5^j (-1)^{11-j}.$

Clearly, for $j \geq 1$ the term $\binom{11}{j} 5^j (-1)^{11-j}$ is divisible by 5. It remains to look at $j=0$, where the term is just $\binom{11}{0} 5^0 (-1)^{11 - 0} = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$(a-b)^n=\binom{n}{0}a^n-\binom{n}{1}a^{n-1}b+\cdots +(-1)^n\binom{n}{n}b^n$$where $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$. [Here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Binomial_Theorem) you can get a proof of this result. Now, put $a=5,b=1$, and you will get the result.